# Transform decimal is removing my zeros

Tags: vb.net

how can I make sure that the results dont remove the last 0 for example, this produces "1.454" instead of "1.4540"

```
    Dim test1 As Decimal = 14540
    Debug.Print(TransformDecimal(test1, 1))

Private Shared Function TransformDecimal(value As Decimal, numberOfPlaces As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim min = CDec(Math.Pow(10, numberOfPlaces - 1))
    Dim max = CDec(Math.Pow(10, numberOfPlaces))

    If (value >= max) Then
        While value >= max
            value /= 10
        End While
    ElseIf (value < min) Then
        While value < min
            value *= 10
        End While
    End If

    Return value
End Function
```

Comment: Turn on Option Strict. `Dim test1 As Decimal = "14540"` wont compile because a string is a string and a decimal is a decimal.  Strings are not like duct tape

Comment: i know, this is not the issue, remove quotes and you should be happy

Comment: Trailing fractional zeros have no meaning, so you cant preserve them.  You can print/display the value in any format you like though

Comment: @Plutonix - They do in a `decimal`. The trailing zeros are preserved after assignment. So `Dim x As Decimal = 4` and `Dim y As Decimal = 4.00` are stored differently.

Comment: Trailing fractional zeroes have no value other than to demonstrate precision of the original calculation 0.0 + 0.0 is identical in value to 0.000 + 0.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really **must** put `Option Explicit On`.

When you don't and you have, for example, this code `Dim x As Decimal = 1.0` you are creating a `Double` and then converting it to `Decimal`. With `Option Strict On` this code won't compile.

When you write this code `Dim x As Decimal = 1.0d` you are immediately creating a `Decimal`- and that preserves the decimal places.

So, if you now write your method like this:

```
Private Shared Function TransformDecimal(value As Decimal, numberOfPlaces As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim min = CDec(Math.Pow(10, numberOfPlaces - 1))
    Dim max = CDec(Math.Pow(10, numberOfPlaces))

    If (value >= max) Then
        While value >= max
            Dim bits = Decimal.GetBits(value)
            bits(3) = ((bits(3) \ 65536) + 1) * 65536
            value = New Decimal(bits)
        End While
    ElseIf (value < min) Then
        While value < min
            Dim bits = Decimal.GetBits(value)
            bits(3) = ((bits(3) \ 65536) - 1) * 65536
            value = New Decimal(bits)
        End While
    End If

    Return value
End Function
```

And call it like this:

```
Dim test1 As Decimal = 14540d
Debug.Print(TransformDecimal(test1, 1).ToString())
```

You'll find that you get the result you want:

```
1.4540
```

The crux of this code is the lines `bits(3) = ((bits(3) \ 65536) + 1) * 65536` & `bits(3) = ((bits(3) \ 65536) - 1) * 65536` which shift the exponent to change the decimal by multiples of 10.